# Invalid conversion from Foo** to void** - why is implicit type conversion allowed to void* but not to void**?

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion

```
struct Foo {};
...
void * p = (Foo*)0; // OK
void ** pp = (Foo**)0; // Invalid conversion
```

As far as I recall, a pointer to any non-pointer type can be implicitly cast to `void*` in C++. Why then is the same not allowed for casting a ponter to pointer type to `void**`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pointer can be implicitly cast to `void *` because `void *` is the generic pointer. However, `void **` isn't the generic pointer to pointer.

[C FAQ 4.9](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html) explains why there is no generic pointer to pointer type in C, I think it applies to C++ as well.

Comment: Thanks you, that's an educating read. I still can't imagine an architecture where doing `(void**)&(Foo*)` is invalid, but the fact that the standard forbids this is something to consider.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Architecture doesn't matter. Doing that( with real variable at least ) is undefined behavior, compiler can theoretically do anything.

Comment: Well, how can I define a function taking a double pointer of generic type as an argument ?