# Passing 2-d array to a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a function that initializes a random 2 dimensional square matrix given its variable name and number of rows and columns (n in this case). This code returns a "Segmetation fault" error and I don't know why. I've tried using & in if-else in the function initM, but then returns "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment"Anyone knows how to make it work?

```
void initM (int n, int **matrix){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (i == j) matrix[i][j] = 101;
            else matrix[i][j] = (rand() % 101);
        }
    }
}

void main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);

    int **matrix = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    initM(n, matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) free(matrix[i]);
    free(matrix);
}
```

Comment: `int **matrix = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));` --> `int **matrix = malloc(n*sizeof(int *));` notice size of a pointer to `int` and without the cast.

Comment: See the above comment.  If pointers are larger than integers on your system, which is quite likely, then you aren't allocating enough space for your pointer array, since you're using `sizeof(int)` where you need `sizeof(int *)`.

Comment: Dear Op, welcome to S.O. Consider using `` instead of `""` to show code *AND* error messages ...

Answer (score 1):

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

It should be

```
int **matrix = malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
```

In your architecture it happens that `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` do not have the same values.

No need to cast the output of malloc, as void* can correctly behave as any other pointer to object.

Comment: A simple , elegant solution :)

Comment: @APJo  Actually now I see that somebody already commented it.

Comment: Answers are better than comments.

Comment: @alinsoar How come `void *` can implicitly convert to `int **` but my `char **` can't implicitly convert to a `void **` - any real logic behind that or ... ?

Comment: @APJo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978561/why-is-char-or-any-t-to-void-cast-invalid

Comment: @APJo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27938860/invalid-conversion-from-foo-to-void-why-is-implicit-type-conversion-allowe

Comment: @APJo: `void **` is not the same thing as `void *`.  `void *` is a "generic" pointer type - you can convert any pointer to `void *` and back again without a cast.  `void **` is *not* a generic pointer type - it specifically points to a `void *`, so it must be cast like any other pointer type when you're doing a conversion.

Comment: @APJo http://c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html (the best reference)

Comment: @JohnBode But a `void *` can't be derefrenced, so how to take arguments to my function which are double pointers of a generic type ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int **matrix = (int **)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
```

The main problem is that `sizeof (int)` is not the same as `sizeof (int *)` on your system, so you're not allocating enough space.  The above call can be rewritten as

```
int **matrix = malloc( n * sizeof *matrix );
```

The cast is unnecessary<sup>1</sup>, and `sizeof *matrix == sizeof (int *)`<sup>2</sup>.

Similarly, you can allocate each `matrix[i]` as

```
matrix[i] = malloc( n * sizeof *matrix[i] ); // sizeof *matrix[i] == sizeof (int)
```

You should *always* check the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` call.  While failures are rare, they *can* happen:

```
int **matrix = malloc( n * sizeof *matrix );
if ( matrix )
{
  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    matrix[i] = malloc( n * sizeof *matrix[i] );
    if ( matrix[i] )
      // do stuff
  }
}
```

Final nit - `main` returns `int`, not `void`.  Unless your compiler *specifically* documents `void main( int, char ** )` as a valid signature, then using it invokes *undefined behavior*.  Your code may run just fine, but there are (admittedly old or oddball) platforms where typing `main` as `void` leads to problems.

---

1. Unless you're compiling this code as C++ or working with an *ancient* pre-C89 compiler.

   `sizeof` is an *operator*, not a function - parentheses are only necessary if the operand is a type name.